# Song doesn't play all the time in Monogame

Tags: c#, xna, windows-store-apps, monogame

Heey,

We created a game with Monogame but we got the following problem.

We got a themesong that plays when you have loaded the game now is the problem that the themesong sometimes plays but sometimes just doesn't. We convert it by the XNA pipeline to a wma and load it into our game with the .xnb together but just sometimes the music doesn't wanna start.

We just use the standard code for starting a song and all of this code does fire.

```
internal void PlayBackgroundMusic()
{
    if (MediaPlayer.GameHasControl)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Volume = mainVolume;
        MediaPlayer.Play(backgroundMusic);
        MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
    }
}
```

We also use SoundEffects but these work 100% of the time it's only the song that won't play everytime you start. Windows RT runs it fine by the way.

Comment: 3 years have passed, still Song hasn't been playing by MediaPlayer (in iOS in my experience, in WinRT worked), did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the debugger gets into the if statement through debugging (or remove the statement temporarily). Another possibility might be that the function is running before the game is fully initialized. You could try delaying the function until the game has been fully loaded.

PS: I can't comment on questions yet so here's an answer.

**Edit**:

Alright, after some messing around with the Song class and looking in the implementation in MonoGame I came to the conclusion that the SoundEffect class is easier to use and better implemented.

```
backgroundSound = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("alarm");

protected override void BeginRun()
{
    // I created an instance here but you should keep track of this variable
    // in order to stop it when you want.
    var backSong = backgroundSound.CreateInstance();
    backSong.IsLooped = true;
    backSong.Play();

    base.BeginRun();
}
```

I used this post: [using BeginRun override](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62939/xna-where-should-i-start-playing-a-song) to play the SoundEffect on startup.

Comment: Like I mentioned my code gets fired with backgroundMusic already loaded. I even tried playing the theme with a 2 second delay also this didn't help. I found some vague issues from other people about Songs not being played but the used an older version of monogame en they said it was fixed in 3.0 and I'm running even 3.2

Comment: I gained the same information. Song seems to work but looping a Song doesn't. I recommend going with SoundEffect since it's better implemented and supports looping out of the box.

Comment: I don't prefer to use SoundEffect because it's suppose to be really inefficient with big files https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/948 Though my app is published and everyone I contacted that doesn't develop them self haven't had any problems with the sound playback. This is really strange and I don't know if I can trust it but will do for now. I will certainly look into your solution and check it against memory and cpu usage if it's an noticeable difference. Thanks for helping so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play a song, use the `Song` class. But make sure you are using ".mp3" instead of ".wma" before converting them into ".xnb".

```
backgroundMusic = Content.Load<Song>("MainTheme");
MediaPlayer.Play(backgroundMusic);
MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.song.aspx).